# Tracing my Data-Entity class and its MVC-ViewModel equivalent class match each other

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, interface, viewmodel, entity-framework-4.1

I'm developing an MVC3 application with EntityFramework v4.1.
According to most common MVC best practices, i should separate my data access layer objects from my view-model objects. I should not use entity objects as view-models for a good project design and for some possible XSS like security reasons. But since it is quite hard to trace the common properties between an entity class and its view-model equivalent while programming, i decided to use common interfaces both entity and view-model classes will be derived from. Such as :

```
public interface ICountry
{   
    int CountryId { get; set; }
    string CountryCode { get; set; }
    string CountryName { get; set; }
    string CountryLocalName { get; set; }
    ILanguage DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
/// entity class in my data access layer
public class Country : ICountry
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false), MaxLength(6)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false), MaxLength(64)]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false), MaxLength(64)]
    public string CountryLocalName { get; set; }

    public string APropertyOnlyForDataEntity_001 { get; set; }
    public string APropertyOnlyForDataEntity_002 { get; set; }


    // this "Language" type is from data entity classes, derived from ILanguage
    public virtual Language DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
/// View Model class in my MVC application
public class Country : ICountry
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false), MaxLength(6)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false), MaxLength(64)]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false), MaxLength(64)]
    public string CountryLocalName { get; set; }

    public string AnotherPropertyOnlyForViewModel_001 { get; set; }
    public string AnotherPropertyOnlyForViewModel_002 { get; set; }

    // this "Language" type is from view-model classes, derived from the same ILanguage
    public virtual Language DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

The problem here is, i can not use **ILanguage DefaultLanguage { get; set; }** in the **ICountry** interface, it gives build error. Even if my both "**Country**" classes have different "**Language**" typed objects, which are derived from same **ILanguage** interface, it says "it does not have a matching return type". It expects me to put "**public virtual ILanguage DefaultLanguage { get; set; }**" instead. But when i put it in that way, then my Database is not being created properly. Because, in my DataContext, i am using the Language and Country entities such as **DbSet< Language >** and **DbSet< Country >**...

What should i do ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I believe this is the problem you're running into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650663/how-do-i-define-the-return-type-of-an-interface-method-to-be-another-interface). There's some explanation there on how to fix it.

That said the Interface might be overkill. I prefer to map between database classes and view models by using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codexplex.com/). That will take everything between the two with the same name and handle it automatically, then you can add/remove extra stuff as needed. Much easier to set up.

Comment: I use AutoMapper between data classes and models too. (Actually i prefer using it only one way from data classes to models.) But the problem i mentioned is; tracing the property changes between both classes. For example, when i change a property name in data class, i need to go and change it in model class too. Sometimes while in middle of some heavy coding, i forget to do it. So i need something to notify me with some build errors. This is why i use interface to settle up common properties between models and data classes..

Comment: And about the "Generics" solution. It seems a good solution, i'm glad that i've seen that solution, thank you. But i can not use this solution since my other classes includes more than one complex objects. So i will have to use it such as;

IUser<T,U,P> : where T : ILanguage, U:ICountry, P:IGallery
{
    ....
}

Comment: AutoMapper has a "verify configuration is valid" command that you can use in your Application Startup. That command is pretty strict and when I tried it did notify me of missing or renamed properties in the data class that I hadn't fixed in the model. You could try running that. I also as a rule make any changes that affect both layers to the data layer first and *then* the model, which helps AutoMapper catch them. Nothing can really help with that except training yourself to do it though. :)

Comment: Yes! you're right. AutoMapper has got some extras for this issue. I actually had read that in the official website in my first visit, but somehow i forgot that features and start using AutoMapper only as a dump object mapper. It can be the best solution for my base problem about tracking changes, thank you. I'll digg into all extra features of AutoMapper. But still, since AutoMapper is an external component, i would prefer going on with my interfaces if it is possible with @Ed-Chapel 's answer. If it does not, then i will try to handle it with adjusting mapping configuration just as you say.

Answer (score 1):

You could cobble it together using an explicit implementation of the interface.

```
// this "Language" type is from view-model classes, derived from the same ILanguage
public Language DefaultLanguage { get; set; }

ILanguage ICountry.DefaultLanguage
{
    get { return this.DefaultLanguage; }
    set { this.DefaultLanguage = (Language)value; }
}
```

This would "make it work", but it seems to be a misuse of the language. Also, if any code sets `ICountry.DefaultLanguage` to an implementation of `ILanguage` other than `Language`, you'll get an exception. Given that this would fail fast, this is a good way of finding a bug early in your development.

Comment: It seems the exact solution right now. I've written the way you replied. And it builded successfully. And also "DefaultLanguage" propery looks all right in an instance of Country object. I'll try to implement it to all my classes and then try it while running the application. I'm a bit curious how AutoMapper will behave in this implementation.